# How to encode a string in Python using utf8mb4_general_ci?

Tags: python, sql, encode

I load a list of records into a DB with collation `utf8mb4_general_ci` and therefore I want to apply this format on my strings before loading so that there are no duplicates. Only `utf8` is not enough.

Comment: In Pyhton, use utf-8.  UTF8MB4 exists in MySQL because the original MySQL UTF8 encoding could not encode all possible UTF-8 sequences.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Declare your column to use utf8mb4_general_ci.